# sails generate <something>: where are the docs on 'generate'?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

`sails generate controller <name>` and `model` and `api` and others.

What are the others? What are the options? What are the commandline options?

Insert here the obligatory "I've websearched high and low" but the only thing I can come up with is github entries for individual generators in various states of ignorement.

So, abstractly, where's the documentation on the `generate` command?

Answer (score 3):

The default generators shipped with Sails are [documented here](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/cli/sailsgenerate.html), in the command line interface section of the reference section of the Sails documentation. Where options are accepted I believe this section of the documentation references them, with `sails new` having the most option usage options.

At the time of writing they include `new`, `api`, `model`, `controller`, `adapter`, and `generator`.

More community created generators can be added, generally by modifying the `.sailsrc` file to include npm package. Here's an example from the [sails-auth docs](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-auth).

```
{
  "generators": {
    "modules": {
      "auth-api": "sails-auth"
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to know more about making your own generators and what goes into that you'd probably want to check out the [sails-generate-generator repo](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate-generator) and docs.

Comment: Thx for link, something I missed. It however says little more than doing `sails generate api -h` and I'm more interested in how they work as opposed to making my own. I saw something random on the web about "or you can overwrite existing with a commandline option" without giving the parm. Are there options; where are they listed? What's the diff in generation of models/controllers between `generate api user` and `generate model user`? I don't necc want *you* to tell me so much as know where the reference on it.

Comment: I think if you want anything more specific than what the docs there provide you're going to have to dig into the CLI generate source code unfortunately. It's [available here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate/).